# Performance/Speed with different types of FeatureCollection filters?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Does anyone know if there is a speed/performance advantage to any of the following three approaches to filtering a large FeatureCollection?

OPTION 1:

```
myFilteredFeatureCollection = myLargeFeatureCollection
    .filterMetadata('START_N', "less_than", beginDateVar)
    .filterMetadata('END_N', "greater_than", endDateVar);
```

OPTION 2:

```
var predicates = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.lt('START_N', beginDateVar),
  ee.Filter.gt('END_N', endDateVar));
myFilteredFeatureCollection = myLargeFeatureCollection.filter(predicates);
```

OPTION 3:

```
var predicates = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.lessThan('START_N', beginDateVar),
  ee.Filter.greaterThan('END_N', endDateVar));
myFilteredFeatureCollection = myLargeFeatureCollection.filter(predicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference. The `.filterMetadata` method and similar methods on collections are just shorthand to specify an `ee.Filter` and apply it to the collection.

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran 9 side-by-side tests with the EE Profiler using both OPTION 1 and OPTION 2 on the same large FeatureCollection.  (I ran them one, then the other, and changed which one I ran first, just in case there were some caching or other effects.).   Peak memory usage was pretty much identical, BUT Compute time was about 25% faster using OPTION 1 (across Reprojecting geometries, Algorithm collection, Table decode and Table query steps).  OPTION 1 was faster in every test run.  This certainly isn't scientific, but it makes me lean toward using OPTION 1 just in case...